# Repeating UIAnimation block, and a way to stop it again

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, core-animation, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I wanted to do a small loader animation to put in my app. I have done repeating animations before with CGAnimations without problems, this time I was going for the block approach.

I am doing a small test but can make the following code repeat:

```
- (void) startLoading {

    __block int count = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                     animations:^{
                         count++;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         if (count > 5)
                             count = 0;
                         NSLog(@"%d", count);

                     }];

}

- (void) stopLoading {

}
```

The above only fires the completion block once, it does not repeat.

**How do I get the block to repeat so that count increments?**

If I get this working and put my animation into the repeating block,
**What goes into stopLoading: to stop the animation again?**

Thanks for any help given:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a finite repeating animation:

```
- (void) animate: (int) count {
    CGPoint origC = v.center;
    void (^anim) (void) = ^{
        v.center = CGPointMake(100,100);
    };    
    void (^after) (BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished) {
        v.center = origC;
        if (count)
            [self animate:count-1];
    };
    int opts = UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:opts 
                     animations:anim completion:after];
}
```

There's a recursion here, so we don't want to go overboard or we'll run out of memory, but if we limit our count (in your example it was 5) we should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I ran into a ton of problems when supplying the repeat option. Most noticeably was, as you mention, running out of memory but also an unresponsive UI, even though I supplied the AllowInteractions options. I found out that [self.layer removeAllAnimations] works on block animations as well - but I like you approach of limiting how long an animation will run - especially from a "nervous nelly" perspective:)

Comment: Block-based animation is simple, but if you want real control, just drop down to the Core Animation (CAAnimation subclasses) level and do everything there. That, after all, is what block-based animation is actually doing for you, behind the scenes.

Comment: You are right. When you have to deal with too much logic around your animation the readability benefits with using blocks are lost.