# ImageView Animation in Steps

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have a small board game, it is all done, except to show opponents last moves.

What I am trying to do is:

Step1: Hide all pieces

Step2: Animate Moves

Step3: Show existing pieces again

What I have tried,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.00 delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut //4
                     animations:^{

                         for (int i = 0; i<[_piecePlayer1 count]; i++) {
                         [[_piecePlayer1 objectAtIndex:i] hide];
                         [[_piecePlayer2 objectAtIndex:i] hide];

                         }


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){


}];
```

Hiding is done this way.

```
-(void)hide{

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.duration = 0.4;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    self.hidden = YES;
}
```

Problem:

Step 1 works fine, but if I skip step 2 and just tries to show pieces in `completion block`it just appear instantly even I have placed a nested animation block with delay.

And how can I achieve this in steps, perform other animation when first one is complete ?

Thanks to `danielquokka` and 
special thanks to this one [Repeat Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616213/repeating-uianimation-block-and-a-way-to-stop-it-again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the core issue is that the hidden property isn’t animatable. Instead use the alpha property, which can be animated. But I don’t see why you’re using the CATransition here anyway. The following code would fade out the pieces, delay briefly, and fade them back in.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.00 
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                         for (int i = 0; i<[_piecePlayer1 count]; i++) {
                             _piecePlayer1[i].alpha = 0.0;
                             _piecePlayer2[i].alpha = 0.0;
                         }
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.00 
                                              delay:0.5
                                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                         animations:^{
                                                for (int i = 0; i<[_piecePlayer1 count]; i++) {
                                                    _piecePlayer1[i].alpha = 1.0;
                                                    _piecePlayer2[i].alpha = 1.0;
                                                }
                                            }
                                            completion:^(BOOL finished){}
                        }];

}];
```

Comment: That works really the way I wanted things to work ;), but one thing that is still left, a user can have one or more moves but using a for loop over the animation block does not work in sequence, how can I animate the moves in sequence once the current balls are hidden ? You can give an idea, I'll try

Comment: I'd suggest having a method to make an individual move with the animation within it, and have it call back to the same method in the completion block of the animation. A state (instance) variable can determine which step it's up to, and call the fade in animation when it's complete.

Comment: What if don't have a fix number of moves to make ?

Comment: You wouldn't need to know the number of steps in advance- as long as your method to show a move knows when it has nothing more to show, it can display the fade-in animation.